# How do you dynamically load different streaming F4V files into one SWF player?

Tags: html, streaming, flash

I need to figure out how to utilize one SWF player/file to load different streaming F4V files dynamically.

As it stands now, I have:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="500" height="314" id="something" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="/images/flash/' . $video . '" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="/images/flash/' . $video . '" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="500" height="314" name="something" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Currently I am publishing a separate SWF player/file for each F4V, but this is unacceptable. I need to use one SWF file to load different F4V files. I'm not that knowledgeable in the ways of Flash, but I believe that the "src" attribute of the embed tag and the "name='movie'" attribute of the object's param tag needs to point to the SWF player/file. So does anybody know how I can manipulate the object and embed tags to make them load a different F4V file into the SWF player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since nobody responded it was up to me to continue my search for the answer to this one. I modified a solution taken from: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=185784 by infinityspiral.

It requires you to add the following line of code to the SWF player/file.

```
FLVPlayerInstanceName.play(this.loaderInfo.parameters.file);
```

After doing this and uploading it to your web server, you can access FlashVars. The one I needed to access was "file" and I simply had to feed it an rtmp call (such as "rtmp://yourserver.vod/mp4:Whatever.f4v") once in a param tag inside the object tag and once as an attribute inside the embed tag and it worked.

There does appear to be a bug with the version of Flash Media Server I'm using though... You need to be careful what directory you're putting your F4V files in on your streaming server until Adobe corrects the issue (so I had to fiddle with my rtmp call above by removing a directory level inside the call to get it to work).